# WPF dynamic data display plot several lines and bar chart in one diagram

Tags: c#, wpf, plot

I would like to plot s.th. alike the example plot [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRmGF.jpg)

So far I am using

```
 xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
```

and `ChartPlotter` and `AddLineGraph`

I would be happy for specific examples or general commands including what the parameters ware about :) - I am kind of confused, since I only find examples but never a detailed specification.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code please, else others will downvote your question.

Comment: I was having the same troubles you do, so I made this, maybe it helps you too. https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts